# Concatenative inheritance and Functional inheritance. Code inside

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, mixins

I'm trying to understand the following code that appears in Eric Elliot's medium blog  (https://medium.com/javascript-scene/3-different-kinds-of-prototypal-inheritance-es6-edition-32d777fa16c9
)

```
import Events from 'eventemitter3';

const modelMixin = Object.assign({
  attrs: {},
  set (name, value) {
    this.attrs[name] = value;

    this.emit('change', {
      prop: name,
      value: value
    });
  },

  get (name) {
    return this.attrs[name];
  }
}, Events.prototype);


const george = { name: 'george' };
const model = Object.assign(george, modelMixin);

model.on('change', data => console.log(data));

model.set('name', 'Sam');
/*
{
  prop: 'name',
  value: 'Sam'
}
*/
```

does it make sense compose the `model` object with the `george` instance? I mean, after run `const model = Object.assign(george, modelMixin);`, the model is something like this

```
attrs:{}
get:function get(name){}
name: 'george' 
set:function set(name,value){}
```

and when `model.set('name', 'Sam');` is executed,the name property is added inside `attrs` attribute not in the root, so model.name always will be `george`.

Inside the same article, he carries on with the same example of code for a functional inheritance, but now he adds a `rawMixin`

```
import Events from 'eventemitter3';

const rawMixin = function () {
  const attrs = {};

  return Object.assign(this, {
    set (name, value) {
      attrs[name] = value;

      this.emit('change', {
        prop: name,
        value: value
      });
    },

    get (name) {
      return attrs[name];
    }
  }, Events.prototype);
};

const mixinModel = (target) => rawMixin.call(target);

const george = { name: 'george' };
const model = mixinModel(george);

model.on('change', data => console.log(data));

model.set('name', 'Sam');
```

He made the above comment
`Note in the example above, we have the 'mixinModel()' wrapper around the actual functional mixin, 'rawMixin()'. The reason we need that is because we need to set the value of 'this' inside the function, which we do with 'Function.prototype.call()'. We could skip the wrapper and let callers do that instead, but that would be obnoxious.`

Again, I have the same question, because he is adding the `name` property in the root of the model object not inside the `attr` attribute.

does it make sense in both cases use the george object with `Object.assign()`?

Comment: This is way too broad. There's like 5 different questions in here.

Comment: I wanted to give some context. The main question  is  if make sense add  george object in the `Object.assign`

Comment: This `rawMixin` doesn't make sense to me, or at least I would not call it "functional". For that, he should just drop `this` and accept the object to be decorated as a parameter.

Comment: @IsmaelRodriguez yes it does, that's how george gets the behaviors from the mixin. It's a pretty common pattern.

Comment: @JaredSmith but  {name: 'george'}  is not inside the `attrs` object. How can I initialize the `attrs` object?

Comment: By calling the get and set methods of the mixin. The `name` property is an ownProperty of the object, it does not trigger the change event. If you want the change event to be triggered, you have to use the get and set (and those are *awful* names, even if he is mimicking backbone) methods of the mixin. Name simply exists so that you can *programmatically* differentiate george from any other object that shares the mixin.

Comment: @Bergi he says in the article "not to be confused with functional programming" although IDK why you'd repurpose a name with a widely understood and somewhat incompatible meaning even if it technically fits.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, I didn't read the article